# VBScript variable loses its content?

Tags: string, file, vbscript

I have the following code. What it does is that it reads all key , vlaues from a properties file.

```
Function readProperties(fileName)
    Dim oFS : Set oFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    Dim dicProps : Set dicProps = CreateObject( "Scripting.Dictionary" )
    Dim oTS : Set oTS = oFS.OpenTextFile( fileName )
        Do Until oTS.AtEndOfStream
            Dim sLine : sLine = Trim( oTS.ReadLine )
            'Wscript.Echo sLine
            If ""  sLine Then
                If not "#" = Left( sLine, 1 ) Then

                    Dim aParts : aParts = Split( sLine, "=" )
                    If 1  UBound( aParts ) Then
                        WScript.Echo oTS.Line, "bad property line", sLine
                    Else
                    'Wscript.Echo "Adding: " & aParts( 0 ) &" => " & aParts( 1 )
                        dicProps( Trim( aParts( 0 ) ) )  = Trim( aParts( 1 ) ) 
                    'WScript.Echo oTS.Line, "good property line",  sLine
                    End If

                End If
            End If
        Loop
    oTS.Close

    'readProperties = dicProps

    Dim sKey
    For Each sKey In dicProps.Keys
        WScript.Echo sKey, "=>", dicProps( sKey )
    Next
End Function
```

The weird thing is that if I assign the value of `dicProps` to `readProperties`, the code does not work anymore.

Am I missing something in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Set readProperties = dicProps
```

You alway have to use Set when working with objects.

Comment: The function name is `readProperties`. Setting `[functionName] = [value]` in vbscript is specifying the return value.

Comment: @KP: True, and whenever you assign an object reference to a variable you have to use Set.

Comment: Wouldn't you agree it may not be a good idea to set an object within function 'myfunction', to the variable name 'myfunction', when the name is used to pass back a value?? That's smells of bad design IMO lol

Comment: The only reason I was assigning the return value in the middle of the function is because I was trying to figure out what was wrong. The last part (For Each statement) is actually not part of the function.

Comment: @KP:  Looks to me as though the intention is to return a value, after all if there is no intention to return a value `Sub` should be used.  The code at the bottom looks like some diagnostics to be deleted once the function is considered working.  The true objective is to have a function create and return a Dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

*(Not enough points to comment, so posting as an answer instead)*

Let me try to summarize the correct but a bit messy answers from above:

- When working with objects, the preferred syntax is `Set objVar2 = objVar1`, whereas scalars are assigned with `Var2 = Var1`. BASIC dialects dropped the once required **Let** (`Let Var2 = Var1`) for variable value assignment.
- When returning a value from a method (Function), the syntax is `FunctionName = Result`, following the rules of variable type assignment, i.e.

  `Function MyObject()
     ' Assign an object as the return value
     Set MyObject = Result
  End Function`

  `Function MyScalar()
     ' Assign a scalar as the return value
     MyScalar = Result
  End Function`